# Sorting a python array by column with different data types

Tags: python-2.7, sorting

I have a little trouble sorting `array` which I obtained from `JSON` file.

**Example list:**

> [[1477298500000L, u'C12', u'Status'],
>  [1477298510000L,
>   u'C12', None],
>  [1477298520000L, u'C12', None],
>   [1477298530000L, u'X15', u'Port'],
>  [1477298540000L, u'X15',
>   None],
>  [1477298550000L, u'X15', u'Status']]

I need to sort `array` by last column with `null values` at the end of list:

> [[1477298530000L, u'X15', u'Port'],
>  [1477298500000L, u'C12',
>   u'Status'],
>  [1477298550000L, u'X15', u'Status'],
>   [1477298510000L, u'C12', None],
>  [1477298520000L, u'C12',
>   None],
>  [1477298540000L, u'X15', None]]

I also need the same `array` in `reverse order` also with `null values` at the end:

> [[1477298500000L, u'C12', u'Status'],
>  [1477298550000L,
>   u'X15', u'Status'],
>  [1477298530000L, u'X15', u'Port'],
>   [1477298510000L, u'C12', None],
>  [1477298520000L, u'C12',
>   None],
>  [1477298540000L, u'X15', None]]

Answer (score 0):

Just sort it and reverse the list:

```
In[33]: import operator
In[34]: test_list = [[1477298500000L, u'C12', u'Status'],
[1477298510000L, u'C12', None],
[1477298520000L, u'C12', None],
[1477298530000L, u'X15', u'Port'],
[1477298540000L, u'X15', None],
[1477298550000L, u'X15', u'Status']]

In[35]: test_list.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(2))
In[36]: test_list[::-1]
Out[36]: 
[[1477298550000L, u'X15', u'Status'],
 [1477298500000L, u'C12', u'Status'],
 [1477298530000L, u'X15', u'Port'],
 [1477298540000L, u'X15', None],
 [1477298520000L, u'C12', None],
 [1477298510000L, u'C12', None]]
```

Comment: Problem is reversing this list gives me:

Comment: This reversed list also is reversing me order if values are the same (first two lines) and I need them in normal order.
Additionally, normally sorted list has null values at the beginning and I need this list also with null values at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my own problem by creating comparing functions:

```
def make_comparator():
  def compare(x, y):
    if x[2] is None:
        return 1
    elif y[2] is None:
        return -1
    elif x[2]>y[2]:
        return 1
    elif x[2]<y[2]:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0
  return compare

def make_comparator_reverse():
  def compare(x, y):
    if x[2] is None:
        return 1
    elif y[2] is None:
        return -1
    elif x[2]<y[2]:
        return 1
    elif x[2]>y[2]:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0
  return compare
```